# Why is the inline editor only available to users having full editing privileges?

Tags: discussion, editor

Until you reach full editing privileges, clicking <kbd>edit</kbd> takes you to another page. When you reach these privileges, you can edit inline, which is much more comfortable.

Why this ability only given when you reach full editing privileges?

---

If someone under 2k rep wants to know what the inline editor looks like:

[image: Inline editor]

Comment: A related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211246/a-lower-rep-requirement-to-edit-my-posts-inline

Comment: Where did your rep go? [You gave your rep as bounty to Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation) o_O

Comment: It's a bait to motivate you to be active on site and gain more reputation.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion ["... aaaaaaand it's gone!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DT7bX-B1Mg)

Comment: as if Jon Skeet needed more rep. He earns my rep (>8k) on a monthly basis.

Comment: @Inf Are you sure that only to Jon?

Comment: @UmNyobe, and how do you think he does that?!?!?  By taking nicael's rep of course!   Silly Um.

Comment: Yes @nic, absolutely sure. All of us noticed the sudden rise in Jon's rep on 6th Aug. And you wouldn't give your rep to anyone who is less intelligent, would you? :D

Comment: @Inf absolutely sure? http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=bounties&sort=offered :D

Comment: Next time I see a "give me the repz" user, I will send them to answer your questions @nic.

Comment: Have anybody found the answer already?

Answer (score 6):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211297/349538), the idea behind this seems to be to show low-reputation users the "How to edit" guidance, which is present in the sidebar of the full page editor but not in the inline editor.

> Prior to achieving the required reputation, you get an extensive Editing Help system in the right sidebar, which is hidden once inline editing is enabled. You can see it if you Ctrl-Click the Edit link (which will open the full-page editor instead).
>
> The theory is that, once people get comfortable with the editor, you can jettison the help system and give them the (arguably more streamlined) inline editor.